# Missing SDK platform Android, API 18

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

While I am trying to Install API 18 it shows only `"Google API  18"`(nothing more). Now if I try to install these google APIs from `Android SDK Manager` it shows a message `"this package depends on "Missing SDK  platform Android, API 18"`. and Install button is disabled.

Does anybody here have Any idea how to install API 18(4.3_MR2 sdk) with eclipse

Comment: I updated my sdk tools as well as my adt!! It worked like charm..

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Have you installed SDK platform tool version 18? In your SDK Manager, there will be the latest version of SDK Platform tools that you have to install first then restart eclipse and then try for Android SDK API 18

[image]

Comment: yes this was the issue. after installing SDK platform-tools, it does shows all the contents of api18 and could able to install it. 
Apart from your answer, it does need a restart of eclipse after installing platform tools to let API 18 becomes installable.

Comment: @AAnkit i have updated to restart the eclipse after installing platform tools. Thanks for letting me know, i forgot that.

Comment: Maybe its good to notice that the Platform tools package appears only when you check true the installed, thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: Click on Deselect All, then install only Android SDK.

Comment: @magorich that is ok but that depends on whether u have installed any specific package or not.

Comment: I had to update Tools > Android SDK Tools & Platform-tools. Close Manager window and reopen it. Then run update again.

Comment: How do you do to access the package and tools options? I have them with Windows, but not on the mac and I see you neither with Linux?

Comment: @Poutrathor in linux(ubuntu i am using) is there. when the dialog will be opened, then go to left top corner of your full computer window there you will find these options.

Comment: thx for taking the time. I did not find it on Mac though (in the top left corner). But it is okay we find something

Comment: @Poutrathor sorry no idea of mac. never used.

Comment: The fact that these packages need to be installed in iterations is such a bad user experience. Why not just disable those packages until dependencies are met? +1 for a very good answer. Thank you SOOOOO MUCH!!!!!

Answer (score 20):

Do this first:

> Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > Packages > Reload

Then retry installing

Answer (score 6):

Another way of fixing it:

0) install other packages WITHOUT selecting API 18,

1) restart the Eclipse ADT,

2) Open SDK manager, then API 18 rev 1 shall appear.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the game, same issue. Neither the SDK Tools not the SDK Platform tools showed up for me. This was a 4-step process:

1. Eclipse/Help/Check for Updates, installed everything that was found, restarted Eclipse
2. Eclipse/Window/Android SDK Manager - installed Android Support Repository (thanks, BurDog). Closed SDK Manager.
3. Eclipse/Window/Android SDK Manager - now the Android SDK Tools (Rev 22) showed up at the top, installed. Closed SDK Manager
4. Now the Android SDK Platform Tools showed up in the API 18 section - installed. Restart Eclipse (or API 18 will not be available everywhere).

Finally good to go to build a new version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation. For me worked updating ADT Plugin to version 22.0.5, closing Eclipse. Then - Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > Packages > Reload.
Hopefully this will help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Message was:

> package google apis android api 18 revision 1 depends on missing sdk platform android api 18

I solved it like the following steps:

> 1. Eclipse -> Help -> Check for Updates (then click on "ok" when asked - do you want to install it - click on "ok" / "yes" to restart eclipse to finish the installation)
> 2. Window -> Android SDK Manager -> Deselect all (then scroll down to Extras and Select only Android Support Respository, when not installed, install it)
> 3. Window -> Android SDK Manager -> Install xx packages

worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks - Eclipse isn't needed. For me the repository was under "Google Inc.", not "Extras".

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed mine:

1. Under "Manifest Cache", click on "Clear Cache"
2. Go to "Packages" and click on "Reload"
3. Check Tools --> Android SDK Platform-tools
4. Install just this package
5. Restart SDK Manager

Comment: A lot of the packages under "Extras" was missing for me. Doing all of the above 5 steps with the additional step of installing just the  "Android SDK Tools" and re-starting worked like a charm for me.  A lot of these packages depend on "Android SDK Platform-tools" and "Android SDK Tools", so when these two main packages need to be updated, the dependent packages are removed - without notifying the user what happened!!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > Packages > Reload

This worked for me. Thanks! Now I can update to 18. I'm new here and tried to vote up Jaguar's post, but I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Seemed kind of klukey, I had similar issues.  I finally got passed the api 18 msg when I updated the sdk tools to 22 which then prompted another error that the tools were degraded on reload. I opened sdk mgr again and had a 22.3 and platform tools to rev19 and some other tool choices available.  I did yet another update to them along with the API19 and API 18 and it seems like it is moving along now.  I think maybe for API 18+ you must update the SDK tools to 22.3 at this point.
Btw, I also got a file lock during part of the process and closing eclipse in the background and hitting retry fixed.
dang.. next it is saying that the ADT must be version 22.0+..
I updated the ADT to 22.3 by using the eclipse/help/install new software (Trying update simply said it was up to date)... one unsigned content error..
Restarted ADT after update.. seems to be working from what I can tell so far.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should make your answer easier to read by (1) not using abbreviations that much and by (2) formatting and structuring your answer a bit. That way it is more likely that your answer gets upvoted.

Comment: Great points -- I also found that hitting "Reload" wasn't enough.  Only when I quit and terminated the SDK Manager process, then reopened it, did I begin to make progress.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve solved with this:

1. Open Android SDK Manager -> Packages -> Reload
2. Restart Android SDK Manager
3. Install the "missing" packages (now visible)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Mac and Windows development machines. The only solution is to reinstall the latest version of the Android SDK. Google really dropped the ball on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as you (purely from problem description), but my Android SDK Platform-tools WAS already installed (16.0.2). All the other packages didn't recognize it, however. I ended up uninstalling the platform tools, and then reinstalling. Then everything else recognized it.

Answer (score 0):

Found from a different website

The steps to resolve this issue:

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Go to Tools -> Options
3. Under "Manifest Cache", click on "Clear Cache"
4. Then go to "Packages" and click on "Reload"

Answer (score 0):

I am on MAC, I faced the same question. I couldn't find SDK Platform in API 18. The solution to solve it on mac is install the SDK TOOLS first, then restart the sdk manager and then I found the SDK Platform in API 18.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, **but with API19**. I installed the following individually, closing Android SDK Manager after each install (thanks cdoner):

- Android SDK Tools 22.3
- Android Support Repository 3

And then I was able to install API19 with it no longer throwing the error. 
(*"This package depends on 'Missing SDK Platform Android, API19'*)

I decided to get back into coding after 15+ years and am completely new to Java and Android having only read the book, *Head Start Java*. Thank you for the easy to follow steps, especially for someone new.

Answer (score 0):

I could not install new SDK from Eclipse (Help -> Install New Software / Check For Updates), it complained the new version is already installed. However, the new SDK did not show up in the SDK manager.

I solved it by installing the new SDK version through command line: **android update sdk --no-ui**

Afterwards it was possible to update the google APIs and other tools via the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

clearing cache solved problem for me. (Tools >option)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with API 19.  The key for me to use the Android SDK Manager starting in eclipse.  Then, the advice above worked to fix the issue.

Background: Because of other command line stuff I was doing, I was starting the SDK Manager by typing "android" at the prompt. - which is what the error I was getting said to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. it needs minimum sdk and maximum sdk packages.
2. you just only installed the maximum sdk ie.,API18
   3.it also depends on other sdk packages for minimum

Comment: and just add the extras and ensure the packages are installed

Answer (score 0):

My solution to Missing SDK platform Android, API 26 ( It should work for API 18 as well)

1. Update SDK Tools
2. Restart SDK Manager and Eclipse
3. Install SDK Platform API 26, which is now visible
4. Install the other API 26 packages

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the deprecated version of sdk manager like version r24.xx, then you need to first update the platform tools from sdk installation menu, before installing anything.  You may have to do this several times (as long as the update notification shows up)