# "Missing SDK Platform Android Preview, API 28" error when installing Android SDK Tools on OS X

Tags: android, macos, sdk, installation

I'm trying to install the Android SDK Tools on my Mac so that I can export projects from Unity 3D to an Oculus Go.  I have version 25.2.5 installed successfully and now I'm trying to install the necessary packages.  Executing `android` by double clicking on it pulls up a GUI that suggests a series of packages to be installed.

I was able to install

- Android SDK Tools  (rev 25.2.5)
- Android SDK Platform-tools  (rev 28)
- Android SDK Build-tools  (rev 28)
- and all of Android 9 (API 28)

Unfortunately it also suggests install of

- API 28, P preview
  which contains:

  - Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image

When I attempt to install this last component I get an error message:
`Package 'Wear OS x86 Atom System Image, Android API P, revision 2' depends on 'Missing SDK Platform Android Preview, API 28'`.  It seems weird that a suggested component would have a dependency on something that isn't present.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?  Is it possible that I will have a functional toolchain without installing the API 28, P preview package?

Comment: It turns out that I was able to build and test a demo Unity project on an Android device using this toolchain, even without that package.  Maybe it's just not necessary.  I wonder why it's set as a default download?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing SDK platform Android, API 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916966/missing-sdk-platform-android-api-18)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916966/missing-sdk-platform-android-api-18 . Restarting the Android SDK Manager helps.